# HttpClient.post is successful but Rest API is not getting the data

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, rest

I am trying to store data from my angular app into database.
I am using `HttpClient` to POST data to the RestAPI. It is sending the the request but API is not getting data and returns  `response code:500`

I have tried logging the data to console and I can see the data but for some reason RestAPI is not getting it.

I have tried sending post request with postman and It works, So I doubt there is any problem with backend.

Answer (score 1):

You need subscribe after post function.

```
this.http.post(`${this.Baseurl}/insertPost`, newPost, this.httpheader).subscribe(
      res => {
         // do something
      },
      err => {
        // do something
      }
);
```

Comment: I am calling ```createPost()``` in another component ```this.createpost.createPost(newPost).subscribe(
      (response:any)=>{
        console.log(response);

      },
      (error:any)=>{
        console.log(error);  
      })``` here is the function call

Answer (score 1):

- If you're not logging anything it's because you need to call `.subscribe()` or `.toPromise()`.
- If you manage to log something, but the response is `null` and returned an status code of 500, then the API crashed (had a runtime error) and your request is likely to have been cancelled

Comment: I have called ```.subsribe( )``` and logged the response and error. And no, API is not crashing. I have tried post request with postman and it works just fine but I am not make the same request from angular app

Comment: could you share the request that is bein sent to the server? You can check that if you open your browser's developer tools and check the "Network" > "Request" tabs

Comment: Also make sure your object has the same shape as your backend API

Comment: These are the [Screenhots from Request Tab](https://imgur.com/a/aUUsIXQ) Sorry I don't Know how else to share. And Yeah I have checked the request payload and it is of right shape.

Comment: Can you share what's on the "Response" tab? The screenshot only shows the "Headers". In any case I can see a 500 so the request is being fired but your server is crashing and hence no side-effects on the database

Answer (score 1):

As @YuTing mentioned you need to subscribe after calling a post method.

```
this.http.post(`${this.Baseurl}/insertPost`, newPost, this.httpheader)
.subscribe((response: any) =>{

//Here response is the JSON response sent by the server when the API call made.
      if(response){

         //do something

      }
});
```